# iOS core data store in iCloud to sync with other devices

Tags: ios5, core-data, xcode4.3, icloud

I've been looking at getting Core Data working with iCloud so peoples data is accessible from multiple devices.
I've been following this tutorial (http://timroadley.com/) best as possible with chugging my app, but i've ran into a few issues.

Issue 1: When the app is closed (not just suspended) and reopened there is nothing showing in the table, so the previous data doesn't seem to get loaded

Issue 2: I don't know if its iCloud or the app, but it takes age to sync the changes. I make a change on one device, its takes 2-3 minutes to show on the other

Can anyone help me solve these two issues please

This code is in my AppDelegate

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
    {
    if((__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // Set up iCloud in another thread:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you MUST change this variable:
        NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"MF4HVVX5DS.Desbrina.Medicine-Tracker";

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you should change this variable:
        NSString *dataFileName = @"Medicine-Tracker.sqlite";

        // ** Note: For basic usage you shouldn't need to change anything else

        NSString *iCloudDataDirectoryName = @"Data.nosync";
        NSString *iCloudLogsDirectoryName = @"Logs";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *localStore = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];
        NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

        if (iCloud) {

            NSLog(@"iCloud is working");

            NSURL *iCloudLogsPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]];

            NSLog(@"iCloudEnabledAppID = %@",iCloudEnabledAppID);
            NSLog(@"dataFileName = %@", dataFileName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudDataDirectoryName = %@", iCloudDataDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsDirectoryName = %@", iCloudLogsDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloud = %@", iCloud);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsPath = %@", iCloudLogsPath);

            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]] == NO) {
                NSError *fileSystemError;
                [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                       withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                        attributes:nil
                                             error:&fileSystemError];
                if(fileSystemError != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Error creating database directory %@", fileSystemError);
                }
            }

            NSString *iCloudData = [[[iCloud path]
                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

            NSLog(@"iCloudData = %@", iCloudData);

            NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
            [options setObject:iCloudLogsPath                forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

            [psc lock];

            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData]
                                    options:options
                                      error:nil];

            [psc unlock];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"iCloud is NOT working - using a local store");
            NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

            [psc lock];

            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:localStore
                                    options:options
                                      error:nil];
            [psc unlock];

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged" object:self userInfo:nil];
        });
    });

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

        [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
            [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
        }];
        __managedObjectContext = moc;
    }

    return __managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"Merging in changes from iCloud...");

    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];

    [moc performBlock:^{

        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

        NSNotification* refreshNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"SomethingChanged"
                                                                            object:self
                                                                          userInfo:[notification userInfo]];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:refreshNotification];
    }];
}
```

and this is in the master view controller

```
- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSLog(@"Underlying data changed ... refreshing!");
    [self fetchedResultsController];
    NSLog(@"%@", note.object);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:)
                                                 name:@"SomethingChanged"
                                               object:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Issue 1: When the app is closed (not just suspended) and reopened there is nothing showing in the table, so the previous data doesn't seem to get loaded

check that you save all data to your managed object context. This should not be Core Data issue

> > Issue 2: I don't know if its iCloud or the app, but it takes age to sync the changes. I make a change on one device, its takes 2-3 minutes to show on the other

2-3 minutes is really fine. It can sometimes take hours to get data in fully synced state. At least I experienced this half a year ago.

Bear in mind that iCloud is not suited for simultaneous use on several devices. It rather offers something like eventual consistency.

Comment: everything calls save context, when making changes, or exiting the app. I've added the save context to the first post

Answer (score 0):

in your example:
NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
use your
NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"MF4HVVX5DS.Desbrina.Medicine-Tracker";
as URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier

it should be like that:

NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: iCloudEnabledAppID];